# Handle time zones in a Rails App with Google Calendar API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I am building an application in which users enter data on a form, including a date and time, which then populates their Google Calendar with events based on that information.  I can't seem to figure out how to handle time zones, and I'm not sure whether the issue is with Ruby/Rails or the Google Calendar API, both of which have documentation which is... not great.

If I enter 10:00AM on my form, the Google Calendar invite is created at 6:00 AM.  I'm at -0400 from UTC, which accounts for that.  Ideally, I'd like for the user to not have to worry about time zones at all, but if I have to have my user choose a time zone from a dropdown it's not the end of the world.

Here's my form (which I am free to modify in any way as long as I have a way for the user to enter a time and date):

```
<%= date_field(:calendar, "start_date", min: Date.today, :value => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), :class=>'form-control') %>


<input type="time" id="calendar_start_time" name="calendar[start_time]" min="9:00" max="18:00"  value="10:00" step="900" />

    <%= select("calendar", "time_zone", @timezones, {:class=>'form-control'}) %>
```

And my controller:

```
  def create
    calendar_id = params[:calendar][:id]
    start_date = params[:calendar][:start_date]
    start_time = params[:calendar][:start_time]
    time_zone = params[:calendar][:time_zone]
    lesson_hash = get_module_lectures(module_number)
    # Time.zone = 'America/New_York'
    lesson_hash.each do |days_from_start, lesson_name|
      lesson_datetime = Time.parse("#{start_date} #{start_time}").advance(:days => days_from_start)
      new_event(calendar_id, lesson_datetime, lesson_name, time_zone)
    end
    redirect_to calendars_url
  end

  def new_event(calendar_id, lesson_datetime, lesson_name, time_zone)
      client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
      client.update!(session[:authorization])

      service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
      service.authorization = client


      event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
        # start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(datetime: lesson_datetime),
        # end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(datetime: lesson_datetime.advance(:hours => 1)),
        start: {
          'date_time': lesson_datetime,
          # 'time_zone': 'America/New_York'
        },
        end:{
          'date_time': lesson_datetime.advance(:hours => 1),
          # 'time_zone': 'America/New_York'
        },
        summary: lesson_name
      })
      service.insert_event(calendar_id, event)

    end
```

As you can see, I've tried hard-coding the time zone in a few places for testing but none of them seem to have any effect on the events created--they're always offset by 4 hours.  I'm using Rails 5.2

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution for your situation, how about using a property of ``dateTime`` or ``timeZone`` to the request body? ``dateTime`` is "The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339).". ``timeZone`` is "The time zone in which the time is specified. ". You can see the detail document at [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: most of the time when you add an event its added at the time zone that the calendar is set to.   you should be able to request the time zone of the calendar and use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateTime must be set up with the TimeZone:

```
lesson_hash.each do |days_from_start, lesson_name|
  lesson_datetime = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/New_York"].parse("#{start_date} #{start_time}").advance(:days => days_from_start)
  new_event(calendar_id, lesson_datetime, lesson_name, time_zone)
end
```

The time needs to be formatted correctly. Try this:

```
event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
  start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date_time: lesson_datetime.to_datetime.rfc3339),
  end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date_time: lesson_datetime.advance(:hours => 1).to_datetime.rfc3339),
  summary: lesson_name
)
service.insert_event(calendar_id, event)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to have any effect--I also can't see where the time zones are being handled at all?

Comment: @thumbtackthief: are your `DateTime`s in the correct timezone? Re-reading your example code, it seems not. Try this: instead of `lesson_datetime = Time.parse(...)`, use e.g. `lesson_datetime = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/New_York"].parse(...)`

Comment: I'll try that when I get to a computer, but that's still going to make the user input their time zone.  Is there any way for Rails (or JS if I must) to get the user's timezone?

Comment: @thumbtackthief not in Rails. You'd need to do that on the client side using JS. My recommendation would be to still show a drop-down, but autopopulate it using JS. That way, the site won't be broken for users if the JS guesses incorrectly, and you're clearly signalling in the UI that their timezone is taken into account